# Counting number of integer inputs in C

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int num[20];

    printf("Enter 4 integers: ");

    int n = scanf("%d %d %d %d",&num[0],&num[1],&num[2],&num[3]);

        if(n != 4)
        {
            printf("\n");
            printf("Input must consist of 4 integers\n");
            exit(0);
        } else if(n == 4)
        {
            if(sol_for_24(num))
            {
                printf("\n");
                printf("Yes! 24 is reachable from { %d, %d, %d, %d }\n", num[0], num[1], num[2], num[3]);

            } else {
                 printf("\n");
                 printf(sol_for_24(num) ? "\n" : "Noooo :( 24 is unreachable from { %d, %d, %d, %d }\n",num[0],num[1],num[2],num[3]);
            }
            }

    return 0;
}
```

For the above main function code that I have written so far, what I want to achieve further is that, if I input more than or less than 4 times of digit numbers, it should print out something and exit the program. However, it does run the program even if I input more than 4 digit numbers(but executes only the first four front digit numbers). Can I please get any help or an advice of how I should fix this problem? I am really struggling on this problem.. Thanks.

Comment: the if in `else if(n == 4)` is redundant because when it reaches that branch n is always 4

Comment: *"if I input more than 4 integers or less than 4 integers, it should print out something and exit the program."* Check, your code looks good for that... *"However, it does run the program even if I input more than 4 digit numbers(but executes only the first four front digit numbers)."* Is your compiler complaining about anything? Perhaps you should ask a question about that... I voted to close because I can't reproduce your issue; I get a compiler error instead.

Comment: oh I see, thanks but do you have any idea of how to fix my actual problem?! Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Start by producing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you don't particularly care about scanf(), use main(int argc, char *argv[]) and check argc. And instead of scanf() use something like num[0]=(argc>1?atoi(argv[1]):-999); num[1]=(argc>2?atoi(argv[2]):-999); etc; which would just be run from the command-line as ./program 1 2 3 4.

Comment: @JohnForkosh I can achieve it by using that main function.. but really want to use scanf for this..

Comment: Why not `int cnt=0; .. while (cnt < 20 && scanf("%d", &num[cnt]) == 1) cnt++; switch (cnt) { case 0: ... break; case 1: ... break; ...}`?

Comment: You could add another dummy `%c` conversion to see whether there was more input. But maybe [this document](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) could convince you `scanf()` is not the best tool for the job.

Comment: @FelixPalmen, there are a number of ways to misuse `scanf` and a number of way to fail to account for all characters left in the *input buffer*, but when reading simple integers (and not mixing string and numeric input in subsequent calls), there is nothing wrong with using `scanf` provided you minimally validate the conversions by checking the return. You have 3 classes of input, *character-oriented*, *formatted*, and *line-oriented*. `scanf` (and friends) provides *formatted* input. I'm no fan of `scanf`, but sometimes, it is the correct tool for the job.

Comment: @FelixPalmen - by the way, great link. That should be required reading before posting questions about input problems when using the `scanf` family of functions.

Comment: @DavidCRankin You can have different opinions about that, but as I see the OP wants a validation `scanf()` isn't designed for I'm arguing it's *not* the correct tool for the job. It's a generic parser function, not necessarily suited for *any* interactive input. But as I said, as it's *possible* with `scanf()`, I just write my opinion here. Thanks for reading :)

Comment: But it *IS* designed for the job, Checking the return validates the conversion. You cannot pass anything other than digits with the `%d` *format specifier* and if the return equals the number of conversions specified, you are guaranteed a valid integer conversion. The OP validates the return, so there is no chance of the problems your link references in the beginning. What are you saying *IS* the proper tool for the job? I'm not belittling here, I just want to understand what your comment is intended to mean.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm talking about the *validating that there's not too much input* part. The canonic solution is to read *all* input and analyze it. You *can* make `scanf()` try to parse more input and if it can, there was extra input, but that's really not the intention of `scanf()`.

Comment: Yes, agreed, that's what I did in my original suggestion. The only part that wasn't clear in the question was whether the input would be on multiples lines. Either way `fgets` or `scanf`, if there is a monkey on the keyboard entering the digits, he will need a `ctrl+d` (or `ctrl+z` on windoze) to end the input. If it's a single line, with any question about the format, `fgets` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement what you want with [`fgets`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) and [`strtok`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) instead of `scanf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int num[20];

    printf("Enter 4 integers: ");

    char read[100];
    fgets(read, 100, stdin);

    int count = 0;
    char* p = strtok(read, " ");
    while (p != NULL) {
        if (count == 4) {
            printf("Your input is more than 4 integers.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        num[count++] = atoi(p);
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    if (count < 4) {
        printf("Your input is less than 4 integers.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Do other stuffs....

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Note that above code assumes that it expects only one line of user input, that it is going to count the numbers in that one line of input, and that the user is careful enough not to input anything else but numbers.

While I think this assumption is viable for some simple homework assignments, it is not a robust code as others stated in the comments. Following code is more robust version with `strtol`. Note that it also doesn't use `strtok`. (Thanks to David C. Rankin for his comments!)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    int num[20];

    printf("Enter 4 integers: ");

    char read[100];
    fgets(read, 100, stdin);

    int count = 0;
    char* endptr = NULL;
    char* nextptr = read;

    do {
        num[count] = strtol(nextptr, &endptr, 10);

        if (errno == ERANGE) {
            printf("Number out of range.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    } while (nextptr != endptr                  // strtol found an integer
             && (++count < 20)                  // so we've read (++count) number of integers so far, also check for array out-of-bounds error
             && (nextptr = endptr)              // we'll continue to read from the place where the last strtol stopped
            );

    // while loop condition can be false on several cases
    // check if it were the case where there were non-number input
    char tmp[2];
    if (sscanf(nextptr, "%1s", tmp) != EOF) {   // %s ignores whitespaces(i.e. '\n', ' ', '\t')
        printf("Nothing other than numbers such as '%s' should be in the input\n", tmp);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // now we know that user input contained only numbers
    // check how many numbers were given
    if (count < 4) {
        printf("You've entered less than 4 numbers.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if (count > 4) {
        printf("You've entered more than 4 numbers.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // We now have definitely 4 numbers! Do other stuffs with it!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, that does require a lot more string manipulation than necessary. Also, avoid using `atoi`, there is absolutely no error checking. As it sits, I could enter `'My dog has fleas"` and your code happily assigns `num[count++] = atoi(My); ...` If you do want to use `fgets` to do *line-oriented* input (which is quite fine), the use `strtol` in a loop making use of the `endptr` parameter to begin your advance to the next digit. `string.h` is not required. You can use your code as is, and replace `atoi` with `(int)strtol (p, NULL, 10)` and check `errno` after the call for validation.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for pointing it out. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Much better. The `count == 4 && *endptr != '\n'` is a bit misleading. I could enter `"1 2 3 4 are good"` and technically not enter more than 4 numbers. Maybe something like `while (count < 20 && !errno) { num[count] = strtol(nextptr, &endptr, 10); if (nextptr == endptr && num[count] == 0) {..handle no digits read..} if (!errno) count++; if (!(nextptr = strpbrk (endptr, "+-0123456789"))) break; }`. Then you could do your count checks after the read loop.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Fixed it!

Comment: Better still! Creative use of `(nextptr = endptr)` within the `while` clause. Still one significant problem... What if `fget` returns `NULL`? What will `read` be? What happens then...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int num[20];
    int i = 0;

    if(argc != 5)
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("Input must consist of 4 integers\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    while(argc != 1)
    {
        num[i] = atoi(argv[i+1]);
        argc--;
        i++;
    }


    if(sol_for_24(num))
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("Yes! 24 is reachable from { %d, %d, %d, %d }\n", num[0], num[1], num[2], num[3]);
     }
     else
     {
        printf("\n");
        printf(sol_for_24(num) ? "\n" : "Noooo :( 24 is unreachable from { %d, %d, %d, %d }\n",num[0],num[1],num[2],num[3]);
     }

    return 0;
}
```

Above solves your problems. Seb and John Forkosh pointed you in right direction in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use the argv[] list directly from the main. I would suggest using [vscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vscanf/%22vscanf%22).

On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled.

So you could replace your scanf with something like that:

```
int my_scanf( const char * format, ... )
{
  int nb_filled = 0;

  va_list args;
  va_start (args, format);
  nb_filled = vscanf (format, args);
  va_end (args);

  return nb_filled;
}
```

and use the return value to check the number of args filled.

Answer (score 0):

GO for a simple count loop if the user enters more than certain numbers increment the count loop by one and return the status to add constraints use if else.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to read 5 numbers ...

```
int tmp;
int n = scanf("%d%d%d%d%d", num, num+1, num+2, num+3, &tmp);
if (n != 4) {
    fprintf(stderr, "error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
/* ... rest of code ... */
```